# The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, google-auth-library

I'm trying to create a firebase cloud function. So I would to run my firebase cloud function locally.
But it do not work how to setup authentication.

I have installed firebase tools : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
I've runned the command `firebase login`, so now I'm logged.
Then I've created my json key with this tutorial : https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
Now if I type `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` the result is `/home/$USER/.google/****.json` which contain

```
"project_id","private_key_id","private_key","client_email", "client_id",  "auth_uri", "token_uri", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url", "client_x509_cert_url"
```

Also I've tried to install the full google cloud sdk and I runned : `gcloud auth application-default login` but no success.

Npm package versions :

```
"firebase-functions":"3.0.2"
"firebase-admin": "8.2.0"
```

I think I've provided enought information but feel free to ask me more if you want.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
admin.firestore().collection('something').get().then((collection) =>
    return res.send({"count": collection.docs.length, "status": 200});
});
exports.exports = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

the code is not important, the most important thing is that even I've done all theses steps, when I emulate my firebase locally with `firebase serve` and I trigger a function, I have this error :
Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field

I can ensure you the json file contains client_email field.

Can you help me to authenticate with google ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Man, I've been working on my local machine for 1 year with no problems, and now I'm getting this error from the last 24 hours. So, it should be a temporal issue.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem. It's likely a bug in version `7.0.2` of `firebase-tools`. I rolled back to version `7.0.0` and it works now.

So the temporary solution is:

```
npm i firebase-tools@7.0.0 -g
```

Comment: 7.0.1 also works fine. 7.0.2 throws this error for me every time when using `functions:shell`

Comment: Downgrading to firebase-tools@7.0.0 worked for me. I suppose the bug is in the latest version of firebase-tools.

Comment: Hopefully next info is useful for someone. After downgrading to 7.0.0 I got the error `Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_grant` which I fixed deleting the file `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` (macOS) and recreating it by running ` gcloud auth application-default login`.

Answer (score 12):

**In short:**

```
admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault() });
```

See docs for [admin.credential.applicationDefault()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#application-default)

Update: Note that this is only recommended for testing/experimenting:

> This strategy is useful when testing and experimenting, but can make
>   it hard to tell which credentials your application is using. We
>   recommend explicitly specifying which credentials the application
>   should use, ... [Source](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

**A little more info**

I had the same when trying to call a firebase function locally which tries to update some documents in firestore database in batch. (Didn't test without batch).

To start calling firebase functions locally, I use:

```
firebase function:shell
```

As you probably know, this lists the available functions for your project.

I called my function and got the following error callstack:

```
Unhandled error Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field
>      at JWT.fromJSON (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\jwtclient.js:165:19)
>      at GoogleAuth.fromJSON (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:294:16)
>      at GoogleAuth.getClient (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:476:52)
>      at GrpcClient._getCredentials (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:107:40)
>      at GrpcClient.createStub (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:223:34)
>      at new FirestoreClient (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\v1\firestore_client.js:128:39)
>      at ClientPool.Firestore._clientPool.pool_1.ClientPool [as clientFactory] (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:315:26)
>      at ClientPool.acquire (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\pool.js:61:35)
>      at ClientPool.run (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\pool.js:114:29)
>      at Firestore.readStream (D:\thdk\Projects\timesheets\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:995:26)

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 500, {
  "error": {
    "status": "INTERNAL",
    "message": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

I was running my function locally using the command line:
`firebase functions:shell`

I was using this code:

```
// Reference report in Firestore
const db = admin.firestore();

admin.initializeApp();

export const performMyCallableFirebaseFunction = (db, { from, to }) => {
    return db.collection("collectionName").where("prop", "==", from).limit(500).get().then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) return new Promise(resolve => resolve(`No docs found with prop: ${from}`));

        const batch = db.batch();
        snapshot.forEach(doc => batch.update(doc.ref, { prop: to }));

        return batch.commit();
    });
};
exports.myCallableFirebaseFunction = functions.https.onCall(data => performMyCallableFirebaseFunction(db, data.from, data.to));
```

I changed the line

`admin.initializeApp();`

to

`admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault() });`

and now I was able to call my function locally using:

```
firebase functions:shell
firebase > myCallableFirebaseFunction({from: "foo", to: "bar"})
```

See docs for [admin.credential.applicationDefault()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential#application-default)

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to set up the Firebase Admin SDK to use the Firebase emulator. You can do it by passing a `credential` property when calling the `admin.initializeApp()` method:

```
const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccount.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
```

You can download your service account JSON file in the Firebase console:

- Click on the "settings" icon;
- Go to "Users and permissions";
- Click on the link where it says "N service accounts also have access to this project";
- Click on the "Generate new private key" button.

Comment: I followed this from the Firebase Admin SDK page and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I've solved the problem after struggling couple of hours:

Short answer:

> Create Firebase-adminsdk key

How to do it:

- Go to `Google-cloud-platform > Service accounts` https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/
- Select your project
- Select your `firebase-admin-sdk` looks like `firebase-adminsdk-u4k3i@example..`
- Enable edit mode
- `Create key` and select `JSON`
- You get the option to download a `.json`. Which has `ProjectID, PrivateKey and ClientEmail` in it
- use the information like this where you initialize your app:

```
// Providing a service account object inline
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
        clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----<KEY>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have created a Firebase project, you can initialize the SDK with an authorization strategy that combines your service account file together with Google Application Default Credentials.

To authenticate a service account and authorize it to access Firebase services, you must generate a private key file in JSON format.

**To generate a private key file for your service account:**

1. In the Firebase console, open Settings > Service Accounts.
2. Click Generate New Private Key, then confirm by clicking Generate Key.
3. Securely store the JSON file containing the key.

Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. This variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you open a new session, set the variable again.

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\service-account-file.json"
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=3

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when running `firebase emulators:start`.

As per the investigation from this bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1451, it seems that this is an issue with referencing the app directly instead of via the admin module.

i.e. this causes the error:

```
const app = admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = app.firestore();
```

but this does not:

```
admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
```

However for the original question, you're using admin.firestore() so that wouldn't be the problem. It seems that `admin.initializeApp()` is never called. Perhaps that could be the cause of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by putting the code inside the setTimeOut() in Javascript.
You have to call the firebase function inside the setTimeout() and add some delay for 1-2 seconds.